# What is the correct way to submit new tasks/callables to a thread pool in the middle of execution?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to figure out the best way to add new tasks to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` pool in python. The code I've included here is a minimal, simple example of what I'm actually trying to achieve. In my actual application, I have a list of tasks that I need to complete across 10 worker threads. It's possible that one of these tasks will fail, in which case I need to create 2 new tasks from that single task for the same pool to work on.

The following code simulates this use case by adding a new callable to the pool within the callback of another thread. I'm unsure if:

1. it's safe to add a new element to `futures` this way
2. the `while futures: futures.pop().result()` will hang until this new task in the pool is complete.

Although this code works, my hunch is that it is not reliable. I'm just not sure what the best way to go about doing this in python is.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait
import time
import random

from queue import Queue

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
    futures = []

    f = lambda *args, **kwargs: time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))

    def worker(i):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            if i == 2:
                future = pool.submit(lambda *args, **kwargs: time.sleep(5))
                future.add_done_callback(lambda *args, **kwargs: print("new callback done"))
                futures.append(future)
                print(str(i) + " done")
        return inner
    for i in range(5):
        future = pool.submit(f)
        future.add_done_callback(worker(i))
        futures.append(future)

    while futures:
        futures.pop().result()
```

Because a new element is appended to `futures` before the thread completes, I can guarantee that the task that "spawned" the child task will not complete until that child task has been created. But, I'm not sure if it's enough to ensure all tasks complete before the pool is shut down.

Would appreciate any insight/guidance